# How can I set all columns to be the same height?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some columns (`div`s) which I want to be the same height all the time.

I'm using Zurb Foundation so the layout is like this, and I can't put `div`s within others to stretch them.

```
<div class="row equalheight">
    <div class="three columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="three columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="three columns"> ... </div>
    <div class="three columns"> ... </div>
</div>
```

It probably isn't going to be easy with CSS, but how can I make all columns automagically equal the same height?

Managed to fix this using jquery, solution below.

Comment: Won't this throw off the responsive nature of foundation?

Comment: Good point, I need a way to disable this when the size passes the breakpoint.

Comment: For what it is worth - I don't know if I see the jQuery answer as posted as an acceptable one. What if a user has JS disabled? Just seems like a pure CSS method is the "right" answer while jQuery is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to come up with the answer myself after having a `eureka!` moment, and thought I'd share for the good of the community.

I used [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to loop through each of the `children` of an element, save the highest size in a variable, and then set that size to all of the children elements.

I bound the function to the window `load` and `resize` events.

```
<script>
function equalheight() {    
    $('.equalheight').each(function(index) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function(index) {
            if($(this).height() > maxHeight) 
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
        });
        $(this).children().height(maxHeight);
    });    
}

$(window).bind("load", equalheight);
$(window).bind("resize", equalheight);
</script>
```

Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following website:

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: I saw this link, it was too fiddly to use with foundation, required either faking the columns using backgrounds, or changing the structure too much.

Comment: Ah ok.  I generally find that css-tricks is a good website for stuff that works.  I'm about to fall asleep so hopefully someone else will come up with an answer that's a bit shorter! good luck!

Comment: @AdamKDean this is why its a really good idea to show what you've seen/tried as part of your question:  so you don't get answers containing things you've already seen/tried.

Comment: Apologies @cimmanon, I was about to submit my question when I had an idea, and managed to get it to work. Rather than abandoning the question, I thought I'd post it and answer it at the same time, in case it could help someone else in the future. Hence why I didn't mention what I'd already tried.

Comment: @AdamKDean Considering how frequently equal height columns comes up on SO, you could have done everyone a big favor and just abandoned your question.  See all the related questions `----->`

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the markup, this would be the simplest way to go about creating equal height columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5KN/

```
div.equalheight {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* optional */
}

div.equalheight .columns {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: While this usually works, in foundation it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: Note: `display:table-cell;` doesn't work for < IE8 but pretty well supported otherwise.